# Managing different .ghci files for different stack projects

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have set up several projects using

```
stack setup
```

for instance, just to give you an idea,

```
mkdir proj1; cd proj1; stack setup; cd ..
mkdir proj2; cd proj2; stack setup; cd ..
```

When I do a

```
cd proj1
stack ghci
```

I start the REPL and my `$HOME/.ghci` is automatically loaded. I would now like to have a different .ghci file for each project. The ideal solution would be that, if there is a .ghci in the project directory, this is loaded, and only if there is none, the `$HOME/.ghci` would be loaded. Is there an easy way to achieve this? Maybe with a suitable entry in `stack.yaml` or by setting an environment variable to the .ghci file to be used (which I could do from a wrapper script)? Or am I going to misuse here to idea and purpose of .ghci with my request?

Comment: ghci will first aim to read the `./.ghci` so a `.ghci` file in the active working directory. You thus can put `.ghci` files in directories to reconfigure it.

Answer (score 1):

The first place ghci will look for a config file is `./.ghci` so the working directory. If you thus add a `.ghci` file in your `proj1` directory, and you run `ghci`, it will load the config file of that directory.

You thus can add a `.ghci` file to the directory, and for example write:

```
:set prompt "test> "
```

and it will load the configuration of that file and thus use `test>` as promt.

Comment: This is only half of the truth: If I create a local .ghci, it tries to load **both**, first the local .ghci and then the global one. This can also be seen from the _Loaded GHCi configuration from_ messages. Is there a way that it **only** loads the local .ghci, if it is present?